# How can access to the objects of a Layout XML from a Java class in Android

Tags: android

That's my question, I want design all the interface of my application within an XML layout but I want to handle all the onTouch events, move ImageViews, etc, from a Java Class, this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LayoutInflaters](http://code.google.com/android/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) let you convert XML layouts to the corresponding View objects in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Yoni is correct, but I'd add one thing.

Don't ever change the XML files on the device.  They're compiled into binary files so any changes you make to them won't actually impact the UI.  All changes you make to the inflated objects will, however, have the expected results.